# Python embedding with threads -- avoiding deadlocks?

Tags: python, multithreading, deadlock, embedding

Is there any way to embed python, allow callbacks from python to C++, allowing the Pythhon code to spawn threads, and avoiding deadlocks?

The problem is this:

- To call into Python, I need to hold the GIL. Typically, I do this by getting the main thread state when I first create the interpreter, and then using PyEval_RestoreThread() to take the GIL and swap in the thread state before I call into Python.
- When called from Python, I may need to access some protected resources that are protected by a separate critical section in my host. This means that Python will hold the GIL (potentially from some other thread than I initially called into), and then attempt to acquire my protection lock.
- When calling into Python, I may need to hold the same locks, because I may be iterating over some collection of objects, for example.

The problem is that even if I hold the GIL when I call into Python, Python may give it up, give it to another thread, and then have that thread call into my host, expecting to take the host locks. Meanwhile, the host may take the host locks, and the GIL lock, and call into Python. Deadlock ensues.

The problem here is that Python relinquishes the GIL to another thread while I've called into it. That's what it's expected to do, but it makes it impossible to sequence locking -- even if I first take GIL, then take my own lock, then call Python, Python will call into my system from another thread, expecting to take my own lock (because it un-sequenced the GIL by releasing it).

I can't really make the rest of my system use the GIL for all possible locks in the system -- and that wouldn't even work right, because Python may still release it to another thread.

I can't really guarantee that my host doesn't hold any locks when entering Python, either, because I'm not in control of all the code in the host.

So, is it just the case that this can't be done?

Comment: Could you require your C++ code to hold the GIL before it acquires the host locks?

Answer (score 2):

"When calling into Python, I may need to hold the same locks, because I may be iterating over some collection of objects, for example."

This often indicates that a single process with multiple threads isn't appropriate.  Perhaps this is a situation where multiple processes -- each with a specific object from the collection -- makes more sense.

Independent process -- each with their own pool of threads -- may be easier to manage.

Comment: A single process is exactly what I need (the process in question is actually a web browser plug-in). Thus, unfortunately, your suggestion does not answer or apply to my question.

Comment: Please update your question with additional facts -- do not add information in the comments.  "Web browser plug-in" is new information and belongs in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The code that is called by python should release the GIL before taking any of your locks.
That way I believe it can't get into the dead-lock.

Comment: Good answer. Remember the GIL exists only to protect the Python interpreter's internal data structures. If a thread calls into some non-Python code, it can safely release the GIL while that code executes.

Answer (score -1):

There was recently some discussion of a similar issue on the pyopenssl list.  I'm afraid if I try to explain this I'm going to get it wrong, so instead I'll refer you to [the problem in question](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pyopenssl/+bug/344815).